# Download a git repository in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, continuous-integration

I use docker.com to build automatically whenever I puch a commit to my GitHub repository. (see https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/)

I would like to call `luacheck` on all files in the docker image and let it fail if there are warnings.

I added a Lua error on purpose and added these lines in my `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN useradd -d /gluon gluon
RUN cd /gluon
RUN git clone https://github.com/rubo77/gluon/ gluon
RUN cd gluon

USER gluon

VOLUME /gluon
WORKDIR /gluon

RUN git checkout docker 
RUN cp -a docs/site-example/ site
RUN luacheckrc .; if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then exit 1; fi
```

see: https://github.com/rubo77/gluon/commits/docker

But it fails

```
/bin/sh: 1: cd: can't cd to /gluon
```

even before the git repository

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to create the directory for the `gluon` user first and give it write-rights with:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN useradd -d /gluon gluon
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git
RUN mkdir /gluon
RUN chown -R gluon:gluon /gluon
USER gluon
RUN cd /gluon
RUN git clone https://github.com/rubo77/gluon/ gluon
RUN cd gluon

VOLUME /gluon
WORKDIR /gluon
RUN git checkout docker
RUN cp -a docs/site-example/ site
RUN luacheck .; if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then exit 1; fi
```

Comment: This works, but it is strange, now I cannot list the site folder if I add one more line `RUN ls site` - see https://cloud.docker.com/repository/registry-1.docker.io/rubo77/gluon/builds/cf6f2055-8b56-4d26-b43b-727e78b8c4eb

Comment: I found out why: docker only executes the run command again if something changed from the last time .  if nothing changed the run command is ignored and just the outcome of the line is taken. the solution is to put everything in one line separated by semicolon